# Java concat with integer and string

Tags: java, concatenation

I want to write a program that would pass an integer and a string to a value-returning method. I know how to do this part, however I need to concatenate the int (which is 2) and the string (which says "bye"), and have it print the string the number of the int. (Example: Bye Bye).

I will respond clarifying the issue as soon as possible.

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: I am not really understanding your task. Do you need to **concatenate** the int and the string, or do you need to print the string n times, n being the int?

Comment: Do you know beforehand if the concatenated string would have the message first or the int first? Meaning would the string be "Bye2" or "2Bye"?

Comment: @RahulSharma  he wants `bye bye` if `int `param is `2` and `String` is `bye`

Comment: @VikrantKashyap I wonder why he wants to concatenate the string and the int.

Comment: @RahulSharma Sir , he is a beginner actually . he is already sorry for his mistake coz he is new to `StackOverflow`. If we are able to understand we should help him out only

Comment: Sorry I'm so unclear, my teacher is a bit of a dope. He told me go find how to concatenate a string to be printed two times, as two is the integer being passed into the method. I'll try all of your methods out, and thank you everyone, you are all very kind.

Comment: if any of the solutions helped you solve the problem, you might want to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate String with int in Java like this:

```
String result = "some " + 2;
```

The string should go first in this "+" operator.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this once I get to my computer with the dev kit.

Answer (score 0):

> try this out

```
private String repeateAndConcateString (int prm_Repeat, String prm_wordToRepeat){
            if(prm_Repeat <=0 || prm_wordToRepeat == null){
                      return "";
             }
            String temp = "";
            for(int i= 1 ; i<=prm_Repeat ; i++){  // loop through the number of times to concatinate. 
                  temp += prm_wordToRepeat; //Concate the String Repeatly 1 to prm_Repeat 
             }
           return temp;   // this will return Concatinate String.
}
```

Comment: The loop numbers make it confusing. It would be more readable if you initialize temp to empty string and run the loop to condition '<=' instead of <.
So you know if you want it repeated 2 times, then the loop would run 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

For string repeat, **Apache StringUtils** have method [repeat](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#repeat%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

Or an implementation without externals:

```
public static String repeat(int n, String s){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(n * s.length());
    while(n--)
        sb.append(s);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Integers can be converted to a string by both references: [String.valueOf](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28int%29) and [Integer.toString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int%29). String concatenation works like math addition (**+**).

Comment: he is beginner not a professional who can find a `third party jars` and add this to `ext` Folder of  `JDK`. So, deal with the basics.. I know you have also giving a solution but this is not exactly what he actually wants

Comment: Ok, i'll edit for his level but leave StringUtils for future.

Comment: And concatenating strings internally uses StringBuilder since java 7, so it doesn't really matter.
[JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
static String repeat(int times, String s) {
    return IntStream.range(0, times)
        .mapToObj(x -> s)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
}
```

and

```
System.out.println(repeat(2, "bye"));
// -> bye bye
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String repeatString(String str, int n)
{
    if(n<1 || str==null)
        return str;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        sb.append(str);
        if(i!=(n-1))        // If not the last word then add space
            sb.append(" ");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Since java 7, appending string using + internally uses StringBuilder. It makes the code more readable if you just use + to appends instead of initializing a StringBuilder and calling append on the object.